# How do I get Parse data as a String out of PFUser?

Tags: ios, string, parse-platform, pfuser

I am currently trying to get a value called "loot" out of the current user. I need the value as a String, but Swift is being stubborn and says it "cannot convert Anyobject to String". The Parse documentation for iOS says to use something like:

```
let score = gameScore["score"] as String
```

and so, I try this :

```
let lootAmount = user["loot"] as String
```

BTW 'user' is referring to the current user. When I try that, it gives error saying it's not convertible. I tried placing '!'s and '?'s wherever Xcode suggested, but it just crashed the app with no error.

So, how do I get the user value called "loot" as a String?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting `user["loot"]` to see what its class is (or if it even exists)? Sounds like it's not a string.

Comment: it returns AnyObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loot is an `NSNumber` not an `NSString` or `String`.

You could convert it to a `String` like this:

```
if let loot = user["loot"] as? NSNumber {
    let lootString = "\(loot)"
}
```

If you're not sure of an object's type, you can ask it using `dynamicType`:

```
print(user["loot"]!.dynamicType)

//prints `__NSCFNumber.Type`
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfect! But, how does "\(loot)" work?

Comment: It's called string interpolation - see [the intro to it in the Welcome to Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292)

Answer (score -1):

You may need to downcast `AnyObject`. Try this: `let lootAmount = user["loot"] as? String` or unwrap your optional user if you haven't done so:

```
let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
if let user = currentUser {
    let lootAmount = user["loot"] as String
}
```

Comment: says "could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x18657fc) to 'NSString' (0x1cbe588)."

Comment: my code: if let user = currentUser {
                let lootAmount = user["loot"] as! String
                lootLabel.text = lootAmount
            }

Comment: I would look into converting an NSCFNumber to an NSString.